# python requests enable cookies/javascript

Tags: python, cookies, browser, python-requests

I try to download an excel file from a specific website. In my local computer it works perfectly:

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://www.health.gov.il/PublicationsFiles/IWER01_2004.xls')
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.content
b'\xd0\xcf\x11\xe0\xa1\xb1...\x00\x00' # Long binary string
```

But when I connect to a remote ubuntu server, I get a message related to enabling cookies/javascript.

```
r = requests.get('http://www.health.gov.il/PublicationsFiles/IWER01_2004.xls')
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.content
b'<HTML>\n<head>\n<script>\nChallenge=141020;\nChallengeId=120854618;\nGenericErrorMessageCookies="Cookies must be enabled in order to view this page.";\n</script>\n<script>\nfunction test(var1)\n{\n\tvar var_str=""+Challenge;\n\tvar var_arr=var_str.split("");\n\tvar LastDig=var_arr.reverse()[0];\n\tvar minDig=var_arr.sort()[0];\n\tvar subvar1 = (2 * (var_arr[2]))+(var_arr[1]*1);\n\tvar subvar2 = (2 * var_arr[2])+var_arr[1];\n\tvar my_pow=Math.pow(((var_arr[0]*1)+2),var_arr[1]);\n\tvar x=(var1*3+subvar1)*1;\n\tvar y=Math.cos(Math.PI*subvar2);\n\tvar answer=x*y;\n\tanswer-=my_pow*1;\n\tanswer+=(minDig*1)-(LastDig*1);\n\tanswer=answer+subvar2;\n\treturn answer;\n}\n</script>\n<script>\nclient = null;\nif (window.XMLHttpRequest)\n{\n\tvar client=new XMLHttpRequest();\n}\nelse\n{\n\tif (window.ActiveXObject)\n\t{\n\t\tclient = new ActiveXObject(\'MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0\');\n\t};\n}\nif (!((!!client)&&(!!Math.pow)&&(!!Math.cos)&&(!![].sort)&&(!![].reverse)))\n{\n\tdocument.write("Not all needed JavaScript methods are supported.<BR>");\n\n}\nelse\n{\n\tclient.onreadystatechange  = function()\n\t{\n\t\tif(client.readyState  == 4)\n\t\t{\n\t\t\tvar MyCookie=client.getResponseHeader("X-AA-Cookie-Value");\n\t\t\tif ((MyCookie == null) || (MyCookie==""))\n\t\t\t{\n\t\t\t\tdocument.write(client.responseText);\n\t\t\t\treturn;\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\tvar cookieName = MyCookie.split(\'=\')[0];\n\t\t\tif (document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName)==-1)\n\t\t\t{\n\t\t\t\tdocument.write(GenericErrorMessageCookies);\n\t\t\t\treturn;\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t\twindow.location.reload(true);\n\t\t}\n\t};\n\ty=test(Challenge);\n\tclient.open("POST",window.location,true);\n\tclient.setRequestHeader(\'X-AA-Challenge-ID\', ChallengeId);\n\tclient.setRequestHeader(\'X-AA-Challenge-Result\',y);\n\tclient.setRequestHeader(\'X-AA-Challenge\',Challenge);\n\tclient.setRequestHeader(\'Content-Type\' , \'text/plain\');\n\tclient.send();\n}\n</script>\n</head>\n<body>\n<noscript>JavaScript must be enabled in order to view this page.</noscript>\n</body>\n</HTML>'
```

On local I run from MACos that has Chrome installed (I'm not actively using it for the script, but maybe it's related?), on remote I run ubuntu on digital ocean without any GUI browser installed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The behavior of `requests` has nothing to do with what browsers are installed on the system, it does not depend on or interact with them in any way.

The problem here is that the resource you are requesting has some kind of "bot mitigation" mechanism enabled to prevent just this kind of access. It returns some javascript with logic that needs to be evaluated, and the results of that logic are then used for an additional request to "prove" you're not a bot.

Luckily, it appears that this specific mitigation mechanism has been [solved before](https://github.com/niryariv/opentaba-server/blob/master/lib/helpers.py), and I was able to quickly get this request working utilizing the challenge-solving functions from that code:

```
from math import cos, pi, floor

import requests

URL = 'http://www.health.gov.il/PublicationsFiles/IWER01_2004.xls'


def parse_challenge(page):
    """
    Parse a challenge given by mmi and mavat's web servers, forcing us to solve
    some math stuff and send the result as a header to actually get the page.
    This logic is pretty much copied from https://github.com/R3dy/jigsaw-rails/blob/master/lib/breakbot.rb
    """
    top = page.split('<script>')[1].split('\n')
    challenge = top[1].split(';')[0].split('=')[1]
    challenge_id = top[2].split(';')[0].split('=')[1]
    return {'challenge': challenge, 'challenge_id': challenge_id, 'challenge_result': get_challenge_answer(challenge)}


def get_challenge_answer(challenge):
    """
    Solve the math part of the challenge and get the result
    """
    arr = list(challenge)
    last_digit = int(arr[-1])
    arr.sort()
    min_digit = int(arr[0])
    subvar1 = (2 * int(arr[2])) + int(arr[1])
    subvar2 = str(2 * int(arr[2])) + arr[1]
    power = ((int(arr[0]) * 1) + 2) ** int(arr[1])
    x = (int(challenge) * 3 + subvar1)
    y = cos(pi * subvar1)
    answer = x * y
    answer -= power
    answer += (min_digit - last_digit)
    answer = str(int(floor(answer))) + subvar2
    return answer


def main():
    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.get(URL)

    if 'X-AA-Challenge' in r.text:
        challenge = parse_challenge(r.text)
        r = s.get(URL, headers={
            'X-AA-Challenge': challenge['challenge'],
            'X-AA-Challenge-ID': challenge['challenge_id'],
            'X-AA-Challenge-Result': challenge['challenge_result']
        })

        yum = r.cookies
        r = s.get(URL, cookies=yum)

    print(r.content)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: im so curious about this question, and can you explain why he successfully request on local machine but fail on remote one with same code?

Comment: @kcorlidy That is a great question, but I'm really not sure. I suspect that the mitigation mechanism might not kick in on every request, but only ones it deems "suspicious". It may be based on factors like the requestor's ip address, whether that ip address has successfully accessed other resources recently, etc. You see that kind of behavior a lot with things like captchas.

Comment: Thanks @cody this seems like an elegant solution, but for some reason, it doesn't work. When I debug, after the `get` with the headers, I try `r.cookies` and I receive an empty cookie jar `<RequestsCookieJar[]>`.

Comment: @DeanLa Hmm.. did you try running the code I provided verbatim? I get the full binary content of the XLS file as output. If I have it print the value of `yum`, the cookie, I get something like `<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie BotMitigationCookie_1....for www.health.gov.il/>]>`

Comment: My bad, I wasn't thinking of non-existing files. They don't return 404 as previously, they return empty cookie jars.

Answer (score -1):

```
you can use this code to avoid block

url = 'your url come here'
s = HTMLSession()
 s.headers['user-agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36'
r = s.get(url)
r.html.render(timeout=8000)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.content)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).